# International-to-domestic transfer at Kiev Borispyl

Tags: transit, airports, kyiv

In a couple of weeks I've got a trip coming up from London to Kharkiv (Ukraine) with a transfer in Kiev (same airline, same ticket).  The tickets were purchased directly from the UIA website and the transfer time between arriving and departing time is 2 hours - both on the way there and on the way back.

I have been in Kiev Borispyl before - both as a final destination and as a transfer point, but previously all my transfers were international-to-international.

Having read [this page on UIA website](http://www.flyuia.com/eng/information-and-services/in-flight/for-transit-passengers.html), I believe 2 hours should be sufficient, as both flights operate from the same terminal D.  What I don't understand though is at what point I go through the passport control and essentially cross the border into Ukraine.

Kharkiv airport is an international airport, however it would really be weird if I didn't have to go through passport control before boarding a domestic flight.

Any first hand account of international-to-domestic (and vice versa) transfer at KBP is welcome.

Comment: Are you concerned with not making it on the flight?

Comment: @JonathanReez Only a little bit.  I don't think UIA would sell me this ticket if I couldn't make it.  I'm interested in the practicalities of what's involved in making this connection.

Comment: Are you a Russian citizen? That's the only real factor.

Comment: @JonathanReez No, I am not.  I am a British citizen, originally born in Ukraine (I speak both Ukrainian and Russian fluently, in addition to English)

Comment: @AleksG 25 years since graduation huh?

Comment: @Karlson Something like that :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My wife has done this particular one several times.

And you will be going through passport control in Kyiv at arrival from London.

But if you prefer you can look at the site of [Borispyl's airport site](https://kbp.aero/en/passengers/transfer/):

> If you arrive at Boryspil airport by international flight and proceed to the domestic departure you don’t have to claim your baggage.
>
> After you pass through immigration control you should proceed through Arrival Hall and customs control area to escalator, then go up to the second level to the domestic area for check-in (if needed) and aviation security control.
>
> If you have items to be declared in your baggage you should claim it. In that case during the check-in at the airport of departure please, notify in advance to check-in your baggage only to Boryspil airport. If baggage was checked-in to final destination notify hostess at the International Arrival Hall that you need to claim your baggage